# How do I get deterministic random ordering in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I would like to randomly order a dataframe, but in a deterministic way. I thought that the way to do this was to use `orderBy` with a seeded `rand` function. However, I found that this is non-deterministic across different machines. For example, consider the following code:

```
from pyspark.sql import types as T, functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(range(10), T.IntegerType())
df = df.orderBy(F.rand(seed=123))
print(df.show())
```

When I run this on my local machine, it prints

```
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|    3|
|    4|
|    9|
|    7|
|    8|
|    0|
|    5|
|    6|
|    2|
|    1|
+-----+
```

but on an EC2 instance, it prints

```
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|    9|
|    5|
|    6|
|    7|
|    0|
|    1|
|    4|
|    8|
|    3|
|    2|
+-----+
```

How can I get a random ordering that is deterministic, even when running on different machines?

My pyspark version is 2.4.1

**EDIT**: By the way, I should add that just doing `df.select(F.rand(seed=123)).show()` produces the same output across both machines, so this is specifically a problem with the combination of `orderBy` and `rand`.

Comment: What is your local spark version and the EC2 instance spark version? Both same?

Comment: FYI I am getting the same output as your EC2, am using pyspark 2.4.1

Comment: @JimTodd yes, my spark versions are the same.

Comment: What about JVM version? I get a different result than either with OpenJDK 1.8.0_191

Comment: @JesseAmano I have java version 1.8.0_202 on my local machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for the additional information from your edit! That turned out to be a pretty important clue.

### Problem

I *think* the problem here is that you are attaching a pseudorandomly-generated column to an already-randomly-ordered data set, and the existing randomness is not deterministic, so attaching another source of randomness that *is* deterministic doesn't help.

You can verify this by rephrasing your `orderBy` call like:

```
df.withColumn('order', F.rand(seed=123)).orderBy(F.col('order').asc())
```

If I'm right, you'll see the same random values on both machines, but they'll be attached to different rows: the order in which the random values attach to rows is random!

### Solution

And if that's true, the solution should be pretty straightforward: apply deterministic, non-random ordering over "real" values, before applying a random (but still deterministic) order on top.

```
df.orderBy(F.col('value').asc()).withColumn('order', F.rand(seed=123)).orderBy(F.col('order').asc())
```

should produce similar output on both machines.
My result:

```
+-----+-------------------+
|value|              order|
+-----+-------------------+
|    4|0.13617504799810343|
|    5|0.13778573503201175|
|    6|0.15367835411103337|
|    9|0.43774287147238644|
|    0| 0.5029534413816527|
|    1| 0.5230701153994686|
|    7|  0.572063607751534|
|    8| 0.7689696831405166|
|    3|   0.82540915099773|
|    2| 0.8535692890157796|
+-----+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I can confirm that I get the same output on both my local machine and an EC2 instance. Also, creating the new column is not strictly necessary; just `df.orderBy('value').orderBy(F.rand(seed=123)).show()` will do the trick.

Comment: This answer is not correct. It's hard to create a test to show why, as you need a cluster with multiple active nodes and you need to restart the cluster and run again to have a chance of seeing the ordering vary in an unrepeatable manner with the methods provided here. Check out this blog post for the correct way to do this. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/group/dynamics-insights-apps-artificial-intelligence-machine-learning/articles/getting-deterministic-results-from-sparks-randomsplit-function/